# how to convert string number to int and then char?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I am writing a program that converts a String "123124125" to integer arrays of length 3 like this:

```
int[0] = 123
int[1] = 124
int[2] = 125
```

let's say ciphertext string has 123124125.

I used:

```
int number[100];
int length1 = ciphertext-> Length;
int count = 0;
int count1 = 0;
char w[100];
while (count1 < length1)
{
    number[count] = (ciphertext[count1] * 100) + (ciphertext[count1 + 1] * 10) + ciphertext[count1 + 2];
    count++;
    count1 = count1 + 3;
}
```

Then I wish to use this formula to decrypt it and straight convert to string of character:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(number); i++)
 {
     String ^ demessage += Convert::ToChar(number[i] ^ (int(key) * 2 + int(key) / int(key)) % 255);
 }
```

But it shows the following result:

> 5553195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195195-....................................1849664615

Where am I going wrong?
Do I need to convert the int to char first and then proceed with the formula?

Thanks. Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: I presume that the numbers you are getting are the numeric representations of the characters you want. I am not familiar with the API but I would do something very simple like confirm that adding Convert::ToChar(65) produces the expected 'a' character. If you're not using that right you're not going to be able to debug anything else.

Comment: i probably found the problem, maybe is this formula:
number[count] = (ciphertext[count1] * 100) + (ciphertext[count1 + 1] * 10) + ciphertext[count1 + 2];
    count++;

String "123124125", by using above formula, it can't get int[0]=123, int[1] =124 int[2] = 125,

and i come out many way still can't work, someone can help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a C#-developer, so syntax might be a bit incorrect:

Try this:

```
String ^ demessage = "";
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(number); i++)
{
    demessage += number[i].ToString("000");
}
```

This way every number is converted to a string representation. So `number[0]` with value `123` will be converted to a string `"123"` and added to the `demessage`.

Comment: Hi, 
 
number[count] = (ciphertext[count1] * 100) + (ciphertext[count1 + 1] * 10) + ciphertext[count1 + 2];

,  Actually i wish to get "1" from string, it won't (1 * 100) but it (50 * 100), i want get 100 instead of 5000, but cant get it...how can i get it "1" then can times with 100?

Comment: I cannot follow you. Please rewrite your question. In your question please show two important things: 1) The results you expect and 2) the (incorrect) results you are getting right now. Perhapse than we can help you better.